# "onclick" events in SVG file

Tags: javascript, css, svg

This is the code in my SVG file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW X6 -->
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="1176px"   height="617px" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-  rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-  rule:evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 1176 617"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<script xlink:href="skrypty.js" type="text/ecmascript"/>
<defs>
<clipPath id="id0">
<rect x="2" y="1" width="1176" height="617"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
<g id="Layer_x0020_1">
<metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
<g style="clip-path:url(#id0)">
<image id="mainMapa.jpg" x="2" y="1" width="1176" height="617"  xlink:href="mapaMain_Images\mapaMain_ImgID1.png"/>
</g>
<polygon id="fil0" class="str0" onclick="changeColor()" points="638,226 638,269 686,269  670,242 675,242 677,237 673,229 669,229 663,228 660,228 655,229 647,228 "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

and here is the JavaScript Code

```
var worldMap = document.getElementById("mapaSwiata").getSVGDocument();
worldMap.getElementById("fil0");

function changeColor()
{
worldMap.style.fill="brown";
}
```

My intention is to call a javascript function, when someone click on a polygon in external SVG file. Link beetwen external CSS file and external SVG file works perfectly, but I can't figure out how to connect the external javascript file with the svg file.
Any idea?

Comment: It's not clear from your question how you are including the SVG file and the script.  It matters for the solution.

Comment: I'am using <object> to include svg files "<object id="mapaSwiata" type="image/svg+xml" data="mapaMain.svg"></object>", and to include i'am using <script type="text/javascript" src="skrypty.js"></script>. Nothing special.

Answer (score 2):

dont use "onclick" in html/ svg, never use it!
start an eventlistener.

```
var el = document.getElementById('fil0');

el.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.style.fill="brown";
}, false);
```

working example: http://jsbin.com/oVoPECIm/1/edit

Comment: Ok, I agree that eventlistener is better option, but that still don't solve problem: How get id from svg file using javascript ?

Comment: you have to define the ID, or you can use get ElementsByTagName('polygon');

Comment: I will try with "getElementsByTagName", but what You mean "you have to define the id" ?

Comment: In your example you have "<polygon id="fil0" class="str0" ..." you defined ID and class.

Comment: I don't think that is a problem because when I put code from svg file directly into html, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The svg is called into an `<object>`, but your javascript exists in the parent. functions called in the object, must reqest the parent function. Is there any reason you cannot call the svg inline?..It would simplify things.

If you have an HTML5 document, the simplest way to load svg inline is to create a DIV with the same width/height as the svg file. Then, since svg is xml, use **XMLHttpRequest** as follows:

```
//---html on load---
document.addEventListener("onload",loadSVG(),false)
function loadSVG()
{
    var SVGFile="mySvgFile.svg"
    var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest;
    function handler()
    {
        if(loadXML.readyState == 4)
        {
            if (loadXML.status == 200) //---loaded ok---
            {
                //---responseText---
                var xmlString=loadXML.responseText
                mySVGDiv.innerHTML=xmlString
            }
        }
    }
    if (loadXML != null)
    {
        loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
        loadXML.onreadystatechange = handler;
        loadXML.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: When i put code from svg into html, everything works fine. But when i finish my map, then there will be a lot of lines of codes. I really don't wanna do that, I prefer keep that code in external file..